# Proving an algorithm must have the lowest time complexity for sorting in the worst case

Tags: time-complexity, sorting

I'm curious if anything like this has been proved, or is even possible to prove a statement like:
**"Out of all sorting algorithms, this one has the lowest time complexity for the worst-case."**

Or stated more specifically, the statement could look like:
**"Quicksort has the lowest time complexity for worst case of all sorting algorithms because X, Y, Z"**

Comment: Any basic Google search such as "complexity of sorting" would have answered this question for you.

Comment: I did a cursory look at the complexity of sorting but all I found were just tables of time complexities. Also "Sortation" is actually a word. Not sure if you down voted me for that, but you shouldn't have.
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sortation

Comment: I downvoted for lack of research; it would be completely unfair to downvote for something I'd fixed. "Sortation" may well be a word but it's never used in this context. (For example, the Google n-gram database has literally zero entries for "[sortation algorithm](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sorting+algorithm%2Csortation+algorithm&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csorting%20algorithm%3B%2Cc0)").

Comment: Any basic Google search of the word "sortation" would have shown you that it was a real word.

Comment: You gave a dictionary link. I can see that it's a real word. But that doesn't matter: it's not the word that's used to describe this kind of algorithm. "Ordering" is also a real word but if you'd said "ordering algorithm", I'd have edited that, too.

Comment: Oh I see, now you're backtracking and changing why you edited it. Originally it said ""sortation" isn't a word" not ""sortation" isn't used in this context". I just thought I'd throw it back in your face like you did with me.

Comment: You have taught me that "sortation" is a word. Thank you. Nonetheless, "sortation algorithm" is wrong. Are we done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting with comparisons is know to be an $\Omega(n\log n)$ problem and we know several sorting algorithms that reach that bound in the worst case (Heapsort, Mergesort).

(The justification is short: the decision tree able to distinguish among the $n!$ possible permutations of the input has a height at least $\log_2 n!$.)

In some special cases comparison-less methods are possible and may lead to an $\Omega(n)$ bound. Worst-case optimal algorithms are also available (Histogramsort).